# C# code for equivalent LINQ query

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have got the following LINQ query and would like to know equivalent normal C# code for it.

```
int[] arrayMain = new int[6];

return (from i in Enumerable.Range(0, arrayMain.Length / 2)
       from c in ReturnArrayOfLengthTwo()
       select c).ToArray();
```

The output of this query is coming as an array of length 6. But I would like to know about ordering because ReturnArrayOfLengthTwo just selects two random locations from arrayMain and then creates and returns an array of length 2.

Thanks

Comment: By 'equivalent normal C# code', do you mean using extension methods?

Comment: No I just mean normal C# code using loops etc. (no linq). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In very basic C# (no LINQ, generics, extension methods, etc.), it would look something like:

```
int[] arrayMain = new int[6];

// Filling the arrayMain with two elements, so increment i by 2
// arrayMain[0], arrayMain[1] (first loop)
// arrayMain[2], arrayMain[3] (second loop)
// arrayMain[4], arrayMain[5] (third loop)
for (int i = 0; i < arrayMain.Length - 1; i += 2)
{
    // Returns two elements to insert into the arrayMain array.
    int[] returnedArray = ReturnArrayOfLengthTwo();

    arrayMain[i] = returnedArray[0];
    arrayMain[i + 1] = returnedArray[1];
}
```

Simply put, the `ReturnArrayOfLengthTwo` obviously returns two elements to put into the array. Therefore, you only need to iterate over the loop 3 times instead of 6 in order to put all the required values into `arrayMain`.

Comment: thanks man ! both answers were fully helpful. thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Well it would be something like:

```
var list = new List<int>();

for (int i = 0; i <= arrayMain.Length / 2; i++)
    foreach (int j in ReturnArrayOfLengthTwo())
        list.Add(j);

return list.ToArray();
```

I hope I understood you correct.

Comment: Can we just write  arrayMain.Length/2 instead of Enumerable.Range(0, arrayMain.Length/2) ? Ah actually we can't since its half array basically !

Comment: @VVV Sure, I've edited :) But it's going to be a `for` lopp. Also, I need to get some sleep :)

Comment: thanks man ! both answers were fully helpful. thanks for your time.